# ui.bootstrap.collapse - two collapse - only one should open at a time

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using ui.bootstrap's collapse and have two collapse buttons in a table row and I'd like one collapse to close before the other one opens.

Currently the second collapse opens additionally so that both are open and are stacked on top of each other.

I searched and found a way to solve this using bootstrap and jquery (http://jsfiddle.net/RfsS9/5/), but I'd like to stick with angularjs.

Does any one know how to solve this the angular way?

Here is my (simplified) code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   ...
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>/<span class="pull-right" ng-click="urlCollapsed = !urlCollapsed">&#x25BC;</span></td>
     ...
    <td>54,654<span class="pull-right" ng-click="trafficCollapsed = !trafficCollapsed">&#x25BC;</span></td>
   </tr>

 <!-- UrlDetails -->
   <tr collapse="!urlCollapsed">
     <td colspan="4" style="background-color: pink"></td>
   </tr>

 <!-- trafficDetails -->
   <tr collapse="!trafficCollapsed">
    <td colspan="4" style="background-color: blue"></td>
   </tr>

  </tbody>
 </table>
```

and the full code as a plunker: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/T5iUXTL130p93tzNiera?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is set `urlCollapsed` to `false` when you expand the traffic panel and set `trafficCollapsed` to `false` when you expand the url panel.

A cleaner way to do this would be to have a toggle function for each of the states as shown below.

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.trafficCollapsed = false;
  $scope.urlCollapsed = false;

  $scope.toggleUrl = function () {
    $scope.urlCollapsed = false;
    $scope.trafficCollapsed = !$scope.trafficCollapsed
  };

  $scope.toggleTraffic = function () {
    $scope.trafficCollapsed = false;
    $scope.urlCollapsed = !$scope.urlCollapsed;    
  };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<tr>
  <td>/<span class="pull-right" ng-click="toggleUrl()">&#x25BC;</span></td>
  <td>A beautiful title</td>
  <td>A beautiful description</td>
  <td>54,654<span class="pull-right" ng-click="toggleTraffic()">&#x25BC;</span></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: restructured the code and used the toggle function, which worked perfectly. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: ... I actually got one more question - I implemented your code which is working fine, but there is a delay and both panels are open for a couple of seconds. 
Any idea how to fix this?
Here is the working code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyGXqM

Comment: I remember seeing that but thought it was plunkr/browser being slow. I realised it's actually slow when you try to collapse an expanded element as well. Try using CSS to implement a smooth transition.